# Using dynamic naming while adding new columns to tibble

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

While using bind_cols () or add_column, I am not able to use the paste/paste0 to name the columns dynamically inside a loop.

```
for (i in 1:10){
abc %>%
add_column(paste0("new",i) = 1:6)
}
```

The above code gives an error. 
How do I name new columns dynamically Inside a loop.

Comment: Use `:=` rather than `=`. See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/2572423) with expected results.

Answer (score 2):

The solution offered so far is going to be somewhat fragile and ultimately useless, since it errors out if the number of rows of `abc` is not equal to the length of the value vector on the RHS of `:=`.  Instead one should use code that creates or selects values that match the first dimension of the data structure. And equally important : the value of that result needs to be assigned back to `abc`. Otherwise nothing durable happens.

```
abc <- data.frame(a=1:3)
for (i in 1:10){
   abc <- abc %>%
            add_column(!! paste0("new",i) := 1:nrow(.))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using    :=

```
for (i in 1:10){
abc %>%
add_column(!! paste0("new",i) := 1:6)
}
```